# Преобразование строки в PHP

Tags: php

Суть задачи такова - преобразовать строки с формата Var_text_text, в формат 
varTextText

Var_text_text => varTextText

Comment: Все работает . спасибо друг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держи дружище, и не забудь зачесть ответ ;-)

```php
$old_str = 'Var_text_text';
foreach (explode('_', $old_str) as $key => $str) {
    if ($key == 0) {
      $new_str = strtolower($str);
    } else {
      $new_str .= ucfirst(strtolower($str));
    }    
}
print_r($new_str);
```

Comment: $new_str = lcfirst($new_str);

Comment: Не нужно использовать `explode` в цикле. - Вынесите в переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё таким способом (более кратким):

```
$str = 'Var_text1_text2_text3';

echo join(array_map(function($str){
    static $i = 0;
    return $i++ < 1 ? lcfirst($str) : ucfirst($str); 
}, explode('_', $str)));
```

Результат работы скрипта:

```
varText1Text2Text3
```

Comment: Ну, а на шаг вперёд подумать? Решение с фиксированным числом частей - бесполезно.

Comment: @vp_arth подумал - исправил, спс )

Answer (score 0):

Способ первый

```
$str = 'Var_text_text';
// Преобразуем каждую первую букву слова в верхний регистр
// Слова разделяются символом '_'
$res = ucwords($str, '_');
// Удаляем символ '_' из строки
$res = str_replace('_', '', $res);
// Переводим первую букву в нижний регистр
$res = lcfirst($res);
echo $res;
```

Способ второй

```
$str = 'Var_text_text';
// разделяем строку на части по символу '_'
// и записываем эти части строки в массив
$parts = explode('_', $str);
$res = '';
// цикл по всем частям
foreach($parts as $part) {
    // склеиваем строку из частей,
    // при этом первую букву каждой части переводим в нихний регистр
    $res .= ucfirst($part);
}
// Переводим первую букву в нижний регистр
$res = lcfirst($res);
echo $res;
```